# Checkstyle plugin is installed not visible in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle, sevntu-checkstyle

I have installed eclipse checkstyle plugin. It installs properly but is not showing up in windows -> preferences. Currently using Mars.2 version. Have tried installing from both the update site `http://eclipse-cs.sf.net/update` and offline archive zip file and both install smoothly.

I have tried uninstalling, restarting eclipse in admin mode and installing again; and restarting ecplise with -clean -refresh options. None of these solutions have worked for me.

Am I missing something here?

[image: Installation details - eclipse]

Answer (score 1):

As long as Mars is an old release, there may be some incompatibility problems between it and the plugin. You should check [Eclipse Neon](http://www.eclipse.org/neon/), where plugins should work without those issues.

Answer (score 0):

If installation works but a plug-in then doesn’t show up in the UI, it may mean that its OSGi bundles fail to *resolve*. To check that, launch Eclipse with the `-console` switch; this opens the OSGi console in the terminal you used to start Eclipse with. Then, type the following:

```
ss | grep INSTALLED
```

This way, you will get a list of bundles that are merely `INSTALLED` but not `RESOLVED` or `STARTING`. If a Checkstyle bundles is among them, you have found your problem.

You can obtain further information suitable for a bug report to the Checkstyle developers by typing

```
diag $NUMBER
```

where `$NUMBER` is the number listed in the first column of the `INSTALLED` bundle.